# Problem on using ALLEXCEPT to get percentage

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a problem of getting the percentage on customer sales in matrix table thta is sliced by store_id and employee_id using ALLEXCEPT function. The percentage of customer sales need to obrain from dividing customer sales measure in current filter by the same measure of the respective store_id, instead of total customer sales of all the store_id.

Here is my expectation of the output and the DAX when using ALL function on the staff_id.

[image: output]

```
% of Customer Sales = 
VAR ALLExceptSales = 
CALCULATE(
    [Customer Sales],
    ALL(
        'Employee Lookup'[staff_id]
    )
)

VAR Ratio = 
DIVIDE(
    [Customer Sales],
    ALLExceptSales,
    BLANK()
)

RETURN Ratio
```

I have tried using ALLEXCEPT on store_id from sales by store table, ALLEXCEPT store_id from store lookup table and ALLEXCEPT on both the tables, still giving me different output.

[image: allexcept]

[image: all except dax]

[image: dax 2 table]

[image: dax2]

Here is the pbix file for testing.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fRrfsikHl9aK06GzAozJ9Wc16Ue0YJm2/view?usp=sharing

Anyone can hint me on?

Answer (score 1):

Replace DAX with following

```
% of Customer Sales = 
VAR ALLExceptSales = 
CALCULATE(
    sum(Table[Customer Sales]),

ALLEXCEPT(Table, 'Table'[store_id])
   )

VAR Ratio = 
DIVIDE(
    sum(Table[Customer Sales]),
    ALLExceptSales,
    BLANK()
)

RETURN Ratio
```

Comment: Employee lookup table does not have store_id column.

Comment: Replace table with table name which is having store_id

Comment: I have tried and it does not work.

Comment: I have edited the dax. Replace Table with your Table name

Comment: Tried and it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [ALLSELECTED](https://dax.guide/allselected/) instead of ALLEXCEPT?

```
% of Customer Sales =
DIVIDE (
    [Customer Sales],
    CALCULATE ( [Customer Sales], ALLSELECTED ( 'Employee Lookup'[staff_id] ) )
)
```

Comment: Hi, your method is working. What could be the reason for ALLEXCEPT unable to produce the same result in matrix table?

Comment: ALLEXCEPT doesn’t preserve slicer selection.

Comment: May I know the definition of slicer selection, it could be building a slicer (for example using date, category and nominal data type) and sync to a chart and multiple column in the row pane in a matrix table (in my case). 

Please correct me on the slicer selection knowledge and the terms I am using is incorrect or could be technical.

Comment: There are a variety of filter sources. Some come from slicers or other visuals, some from report/page/visual filters (via the filter pane), and some from the local context of the current visual (e.g. rows and columns in a matrix visual). ALLSELECTED removes local context but preserves the others (this is an an oversimplification but reality is way more complicated). ALLEXCEPT removes all filters (from all sources) on the specified table except for the columns included as arguments and these columns retain all filters (from all sources).